# How To Make Icon Bounce Until It Loses Hover With Jquery?

Tags: jquery

I am unable to get my icon to keep bouncing up and down up and down on hover, but I can only manage to get it to do it one full cycle per hover.

Here is the page. The element/icon is the "business" image. http://fdtcincinnati.com/landing-page

How is this effect (or a similar blink effect) achieved?

Thanks!

EDIT

Here is the Jquery/JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var timeout = '';
    var intervalId = null;
    var bouncing = false;

    $("a#business").hover(function() {

        bouncing = true;
        bounce($(this), bouncing, 160, 170);

    }, function() {

        bouncing = false;
        bounce($(this), bouncing, 160, 170);

    });

});

function bounce(ob, bouncing, val1, val2) {

    if (! bouncing) {

        ob.animate({ "top": val1 + "px" }, 400);

    } else {

        ob.animate({ "top": val1 + "px" }, 400).animate({ "top": val2 + "px" }, 400);

        setTimeout(bounce(ob, bouncing, val1, val2), 800);

    }

}
```

Here is the HTML:

```
    <body id="landing_page">

    <div id="fp_wrapper">

        <h1 id="lp_logo"><a href="/">First Discount Travel Cincinnati</a></h1>

        <a id="business" href="">Business</a>

        <a id="leisure" href="">Business</a>

        <p id="below">Click one of the couples to continue!</p>

    </div><!-- end fp_wrapper -->

</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you can make use of the jQuery UI bounce effect. This simplifies the amount of code you need. I attached a data object to the `business` image so that you don't need to rely on global variables. Then you use the callback of the bounce effect to loop the animation.

http://jsfiddle.net/RkNV2/2/

```
$('img').hover( 
    function() { $(this).data('bounce', true); bounce($(this));}, 
    function() { $(this).data('bounce', false);
});

function bounce($elem) {
    $elem.effect('bounce', { times: 1, distance: 10 }, 500, function() {
        if ($(this).data('bounce')) bounce($elem);
        else $elem.stop();
    });
}
```

The bounce effect gives you control over # of bounces, distance of bounces, direction and mode.

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Bounce

Answer (score 1):

Some really generic code for you - set a flag indicating whether to keep going and clear that flag when the hover ends:

```
var bouncing = false;

$("#yourelement").hover(
   function() {
      bouncing = true;
      yourBounceFunction();
   },
   function() {
      bouncing = false;
   }
);

function yourBounceFunction() {
   if (!bouncing) {
      // stop the animation
   } else {
      // continue current animation
   }
}
```

I can't really offer anything more specific without seeing your code.

**EDIT, now that you've posted your code:** The following line from your code won't work:

```
setTimeout(bounce(ob, bouncing, val1, val2), 800);
```

You need to pass `setTimeout()` a function reference as the first parameter. Your code actually calls the `bounce()` function with those parameters and passes the result (undefined) to `setTimout()`. Try the following, which defines an anonymous function as the parameter to `setTimeout()` and within that function calls your function:

```
setTimeout(function(){ bounce(ob, bouncing, val1, val2); }, 800);
```

Having said that, you may want to get rid of the timeout and just call the function again from within the complete handler for the animation.

Also, you shouldn't be passing `bouncing` as a parameter to the function, you want the function to access the same variable as the hover handlers. So move the bounce function definition into your document.ready (or declare the `bouncing` variable as a global, outside document.ready):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var bouncing = false;

    $("a#business").hover(function() {
       bouncing = true;
       bounce($(this), 160, 170);           
    }, function() {
       bouncing = false;
    });

    function bounce(ob, val1, val2) {
       if (!bouncing) { 
          // stop bouncing: animate back to default position
          ob.animate({ "top": val1 + "px" }, 400);
       } else {
          ob.animate({ "top": val1 + "px" }, 400)
            .animate({ "top": val2 + "px" }, 400, function() {
                // animation just finished, so go again:
                bounce(ob, val1, val2);
            });
       }
    }

});
```

I haven't tested that last option, but the idea is that you provide a callback function for jQuery to call once the animation is complete, so within the callback you call your bounce function again. You don't need to test the `bouncing` variable again in the callback because the first thing your bounce function does is test it.

(`.animate()` takes an optional callback function as a parameter after the duration - see the [jQuery `.animate()` doco](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) for more info on how the complete callback function works.)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write this. The first solution only caused it to fire once. I'm trying the second as we speak.

Comment: You're welcome. In principle either solution should work, it's just a question of how to integrate one or the other with your existing code. Which I can't advise you on without seeing your existing code...

Comment: Here is the page with the second solution employed. Only bounces once again... I'm even calling the same function recursively.

http://fdtcincinnati.com/landing-page

Comment: Can you edit your question to include (just) the relevant code including your bounce function and your hover handler? (I'm too lazy to go looking through page source to find the bit that matters, and also in general it makes your question and any answers more useful to other SO users who may come across it later long after your demo page is gone).

Answer (score 0):

I guess it depends what you mean by 'bounce'

If you just want it to be animated you don't need to do it with jquery. Can you just use an animated gif & define some css for the hover state?

```
#youricon:hover {
  background-image: url(images/bounce.gif);
}
```